# How can I use more memory?

Tags: c++, memory

I got the following error:

```
std::bad_array_new_length at memory location 0x00B3F9D8
```

It is because of this part:

```
U32 rayCountSqrt = (U32)(std::ceil(objWidthLambda * (T)(observation.rayPerLam_) + 1.0)) + 1;
rayPool.Initialize( rayCountSqrt);
```

And if we look at the `Initilialize` method

```
void Initialize( const U32& rayCountSqrt )
{
    Reset();
    rayCountSqrt_ = rayCountSqrt;
    rayCount_ =  rayCountSqrt * rayCountSqrt;
    rayArea_ = 0;
    rayTubeArray_.reset( new RayTube< T >[ rayCount_ ], []( RayTube< T >* ptr ){ delete[] ptr; } );
    init_ = true;
}
```

Problem is probably located here, because when I pass for example `10` to `Initialize` I get no errors. My `rayCountSqrt` is `86354` and I don't know if it's too big to handle.

How can I fix this? I really need to pass large numbers to this function in order to get good approximations.

Comment: `rayCount_` will be  86354 * 86354  == 7,457,013,316 which is a big number even without taking into account `sizeof(RayTube<T>)`. You'll probably need a lot more RAM...

Comment: A side note: instead of using a smart pointer to a C style array, you can use `std::vector`.

Comment: Said differently, you should try to use a different algo...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? @user17732522

Comment: Random note: passing `rayCountSqrt` as `const U32&` is pointless and actually slower than just passing it as `const U32` because the reference requires an indirection to access which is unnecessary. A U32 is already smaller than the pointer you're actually passing in most systems.

Comment: oh, thanks. I somehow thought passing reference is faster than passing values

Comment: @merovingian it can be for large things, but for small things it's generally not worth it. What that line is depends on architecture and compiler. But sub pointer size things are almost never faster as references unless you're using them as out parameters. Which you're not here.

Comment: @merovingian I don't think there is really much to explain. You probably don't have enough memory, so you will need to find a way to do it with less memory. I am surprised however that you got a `std::bad_array_new_length` instead of a `std::bad_alloc`. Are you using this on a 32bit platform or is `rayCount_` a signed 32bit variable? On a 64bit one it should be possible to have arrays that large at least in principle and only the actual allocation attempt may fail (with `std::bad_alloc`).

Comment: Also if `U32` is a 32bit unsigned integer, then `86354 * 86354` will not be representable in it anyway and wrap around, giving you some unintended value.

Comment: rayCount_ is 32 bit unsigned integer. I tried uint64 too but I still get the std::bad_array_new_length error @user17732522

Comment: @merovingian Well, going by how the pointer value `0x00B3F9D8` is presented in the error message, you are on a 32bit machine though, so in that case a program simply can't have so much memory.

Comment: I don't know about the error value but I am on a 64bit machine. @user17732522

Comment: @merovingian Are you also compiling for 64bit? All of the types involved should be using a 64bit integer type instead. Also, what is `sizeof(RayTube< T >)` and how many GB RAM do you have available?

Comment: One interesting thing: I just passed rayCountSqrt = 5000. And I got the std::bad_alloc error

Comment: So when I pass like 8k I get bad_length and less than that I get bad_alloc, that is interesting

Comment: sizeof(RayTube< T >) is 60 bits and I have 16 GB of ram. By the way I am using C++ AMP. But I don't think it is relevant? @user17732522

Comment: @merovingian *and I have 16 GB of ram* -- You could have 100GB or RAM, it won't make any difference if your application is 32-bit.  A 32-bit application is limited to < 4GB of memory.

Comment: *How can I fix this?* -- Build a 64-bit application instead of a 32-bit one.